# Lastrow not being identified due to merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I have a data set where some cells are merged.

There is not one column where they are not merged, and some columns have no entries.

I want to find the last row so that I can add a formula to a column up until the last row.

At the moment my last row is a merged cell with 2 entries. My formula has been added up until the 
second to last row.

This is my code to find the last row, based on column A (which has merged cells).

```
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

IT's just not picking up the last row due to the merged cells. There's no way I can unuse them.

I want to use the last row for the following code:

```
Range("AB5") = "Age Year/Month"
    Range("AB6:AB" & lastrow).Formula = 
    "=DATEDIF(RC[-2],TODAY(),""Y"") & "" Years, "" & 
    DATEDIF(RC[-2],TODAY(),""YM"") & "" Months """
```

which works for everything other than my last row which hasn't been picked up.

I would also like to put the today() somewhere on my sheet and reference the cell in the above formula,
rather than use today() all the time which I know is volatile.

Any advice on the last row with the merged cells issue? Sorry, for some reason it's not letting me add comments.

I can't add a picture as it is confidential data I'm using. Column A is the most complete column, just the last 2 rows in col A are merged. So it's not picking up that the last row is in fact the last row, it's picking up the first of the two merged cells as the last one

Comment: I've tried that but then the formula that relies on lastrow does not work, it just puts the formula into cells AB6 to the bottom as text instead

Comment: If the lastrow has merged cells then it's possible that the last cell may not be in Col A what is the NAME of the last cell ? Can you share the picture of the worksheet?

Comment: Sorry, I've just been able to add a comment now!

I can't share sorry as it has confidential data. . Column A is the most complete column, just the last 2 rows in col A are merged. So it's not picking up that the last row is in fact the last row, it's picking up the first of the two merged cells as the last one

Answer (score 0):

Why not try

```
lastrow = Sheets("UrSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Try the below

```
Dim cel As Range
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set cel = Cells(lastrow, 1)
lastrow = lastrow + cel.MergeArea.Rows.Count - 1
MsgBox lastrow
```

Comment: I've tried that but then the formula that relies on lastrow does not work, it just puts the formula into cells AB6 to the bottom as text instead–

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11128307)

Comment: @Magisch  but the questioner was stuck at identifying the 'lastrow'  which if solved entire problem is solved.

Comment: I did try the users suggestion but then it resulted in my formulas displaying as text in this line of code: (not sure why it's not displaying code properly, sorry!)



Range("AB5") = "Age Year/Month"
    Range("AB6:AB" & lastrow).Formula = 
    "=DATEDIF(RC[-2],TODAY(),""Y"") & "" Years, "" & 
    DATEDIF(RC[-2],TODAY(),""YM"") & "" Months """

Comment: Are you sure the formula is correct and working fine when you place in a cell manually. I also have a doubt for month shouldnt it be "M" instead of "YM"

Comment: It works fine in a cell manually. But I just don't want to keep using today() in the formula, I'd rather reference a cell which has today() in it, and keep using this cell.

My main concern is the merged cells meaning the last row is not identified properly if it is merged

Comment: Actually, the above does work, however it adds the formula for the row below the last row, so it's counting an extra row for some reason

Comment: It also counts blank rows that are formated( borders, cells formating...) even though cells are empty.

Comment: Ah. The problem I have is that there is text and a graphic up to row 5. Then row 5 is the column headings, row 6 is where the data starts. Could I modify that code to only count rows that have data either in those cells or to the right in any other column? It's harder than I thought to do one simple thing :(

Comment: Plus the cells that it has counted are not formatted, nor do they have a border?

Comment: Any cell in that row been formatted, used, borders?

Comment: Try deleting all the rows below your last row manually and try the code

Comment: No none. I can't remove the rows below that as this template is for a colleague who will just want to open their data and then the code should run automatically, without them having to manually intervene.

I've manually ensured that there is no formatting, no borders etc and then retried and I'm still getting the row below being filled in with my formula.

On another data set, all rows below my last row were filled in :(

Comment: What I'm asking is to see if the code is working when deleting the rows below. I'm sure that there got to be something by usedrange is giving+1. Are there any other options to check if formula is placing in correct cell like it's adjacent should have value

Comment: Have one suggestion. Try to use the same last row you tried earlier, but not on A column, instead try on any other column where there are no merge cells

Comment: Have one suggestion. Try to use the same last row you tried earlier, but not on A column, instead try on any other column where there are no merge cells

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. There are no entire columns that don't have at least some merged cells unfortunately.

On other data I use the formula is being put in 100s of rows below, not just 1.

I can't think of any way around this, it's quite frustrating

Comment: If Possible can you please share a sample snap shot of your data. Will have a look and think of other alternatives

Comment: Hi, sorry but I'm unable to as it's confidential people data. I can try and mock some up? but not sure how I'd share it?

Comment: I tried the added answer and it worked fine for me. You should check and let me know if your problem is solved or not.